# What would be a good program for running a Discord bot with Javascript?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, discord.js

(discord.js/node.js)
Currently, I use https://replit.com/, but I am wondering if I can do better for free. It has to be free and web-based because I also need to use it on a restricted access device.

Comment: You could consider hosting on Heroku - [How To](https://anidiots.guide/hosting/heroku).

Comment: you can using glitch for host bot for free

Comment: Glitch is not an option as they have updated their terms on ping. https://blog.glitch.com/post/ping-services

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). I personally use it. You can host your bot on GitHub and connect the repository to Heroku.

Then whenever you push changes to your bot repository, it automatically updates your Heroku app and your bot will restart itself with the new updates.